# Delete similarly named indexes from elasticsearch Head Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to execute a curl request from the elasticsearch head plugin in order to delete all the similarly named indexes. I am using the following command but getting an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_search` endpoint doesn't support the HTTP DELETE method.

Do this instead:

1. In the location field, set `parkingapi-farhad-*`
2. Select the DELETE method
3. Click the "Request" button

You can also do it using a simple curl:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9500/parkingapi-farhad-*
```